# Delegate function cellForRowAt called more times than necessary, resulting in duplicate entries

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm creating a simple task tracking application using TableView and UITableViewCells. I've created three tasks via the addButtonClicked() function, but it results in five tasks being created due to the delegate function cellForRowAt being called more times than necessary. For example, if I have the tasks: Shop, Watch TV, Eat, it will display Shop, Watch TV, Eat, Shop, Watch TV, with the extraneous elements having incorrect positions. I'm inexperienced in using these UI components, so any help is appreciated. I've attached the relevant code pieces below:

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
let tableView: UITableView = {
        let table = UITableView()
        table.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "itemCell")
        return table
}()
    
private var itemCells = [PlannerItem]()

//UI setup.
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        title = currDate()
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        populateTableItems()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.frame = view.bounds
        
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addButtonClicked))
    }

//Handling Add Task Functionality
 @objc func addButtonClicked()
    {
        let addMenu = UIAlertController(title: "Add Item", message: "Enter the associated information.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        addMenu.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) in
                    textField.placeholder = "Title"
                }
        addMenu.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) in
                    textField.placeholder = "Category"
                }
        addMenu.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) in
                    textField.placeholder = "Date (mm::dd::yy)"
                }
        
        addMenu.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save Entry", style: .cancel, handler: {
            _ in guard let titleInput = addMenu.textFields?[0],
                       let categoryInput = addMenu.textFields?[1],
                       let dueDateInput = addMenu.textFields?[2],
                       let titleInputText = titleInput.text,
                       let categoryInputText = categoryInput.text,
                       let dueDateInputText = dueDateInput.text,
                       !titleInputText.isEmpty && !categoryInputText.isEmpty && !dueDateInputText.isEmpty
            else {
                return
            }
        
        let dateFormatChecker = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatChecker.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
        let date = dateFormatChecker.date(from: dueDateInputText)
        
        if date != nil
        {
            self.addItem(title: titleInputText, category: categoryInputText, dueDate: date!)
        }
        else
        {
            return
        }
        
        }))
        
        present(addMenu, animated: true)
    }

//Delegate Function
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let item = itemCells[indexPath.row]
        print(indexPath.row)
        let itemCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "itemCell", for: indexPath)
        
        let cellTopLeftY = itemCell.frame.origin.y
        let cellWidth = itemCell.frame.size.width
        let cellHeight = itemCell.frame.size.height
        
        let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10.0, y: cellTopLeftY, width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight / 2))
        //titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: titleLabel.font.fontName, size: 15)
        titleLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15.0)
        titleLabel.text = item.title
        
        let categoryLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10.0, y: cellTopLeftY + cellHeight / 2, width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight / 2))
        categoryLabel.font = UIFont(name: categoryLabel.font.fontName, size: 12)
        categoryLabel.text = item.category
        
        
        itemCell.contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
        itemCell.contentView.addSubview(categoryLabel)
        return itemCell
    }

func addItem(title: String, category: String, dueDate: Date)
    {
        let item = PlannerItem(context: context)
        item.title = title
        item.category = category
        item.dueDate = dueDate
        
        do
        {
            try context.save()
            populateTableItems()
        }
        catch
        {
            
        }
    }

//Populates/Refreshes Backing Task List 
func populateTableItems()
    {
        do
        {
            itemCells = try context.fetch(PlannerItem.fetchRequest())
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm sure `cellForRow` is called as much/little as necessary. But you should consider that cells are reused. You are adding 2 labels to the cell all the time. At the moment the cell is reused you will have 4 labels and so on. There is the actual problem.

Comment: I see, would the most appropriate way to resolve this be to define a cell outside of cellForRow to reuse the labels instead of adding labels each time it is called?

Comment: No, just check if the labels exist. If yes don't add them. You could assign tags to the labels for a efficient check.